# Misleading shortened flair popup text

Tags: support, profile-page

When I hover the mouse pointer over my Gravatar on SO, I see a statement signed by Vladimir Bulatov:

[image]

While my original text is:

```
Using [Steve Jessop's][1] statement as a recursive function:   

... blah ... blah ...  

grAvatar made by [**Vladimir Bulatov**][2]
```

**Edit**

'About me' text edited as per Marc's suggestion

```
[grAvatar made by **Vladimir Bulatov**][2]
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Looking at it in Firebug, I see that that link is placed in an extra span labeled `um-links`. This seems to be afeature, not a bug. Not visible links in the description seem to be extractd into that extra field.

Comment: @Padded Ok. Let's call it `Unexpected behavior` ... but I don't see such a tag :)

Comment: Note that your content on SO is licensed under [a creative commons license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). I don't think you can override that.

Comment: @hammar: Yes, the content...but not the Avatar. I doubt that it falls under the CC licensing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The footer contains the first few links that weren't in the shortened text. In your case, perhaps extend the link to include the full context, i.e.

```
[gravatar made by **Vladimir...
```

Comment: Ok. I wasn't aware that the link was a 'footer'. Thanks